# Java - Load additional class at JVM startup

Tags: java, class, load, jvm, boot

I'd like to load an additional class at JVM startup. Specifically, the class should be loaded after all core libraries are loaded (so after `rt.jar` and `lib/ext` at least).

The class isn't referenced anywhere. It contains a static block setting a JVM-wide proxy that we'd like all URL connections to use.

I've tried the `-Xbootclasspath/a`, `-Xbootclasspath/p` options. With `-verbose:class` added to `JVM_OPTS` as well the load/open output created by the `-Xbootclasspath` variant indicates all core libraries are "loaded" while my JAR is simply "opened".

Is there a way to force load a class - or better still all classes in a JAR - at JVM bootup after all core classes have loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research I couldn't find any better way than a custom classloader.

Here's what I wrote. It inherently uses the default classloader for all classloading methods, but offers access to a non-static initializer where custom class loading/referencing can occur.

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    {
        // Custom class loading goes in this non-static initializer.
        loadClass("java.org.myorganisation.package.MyClass");
    }

    public CustomClassLoader() {
        super(CustomClassLoader.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }
}
```

Specify the custom class loader by defining system property `-Djava.system.class.loader=com.anon.mypackage.CustomClassLoader`.

Comment: In your answer, when you wrote "Custom class loading goes in this static block." did you mean that you just reference the static class to be loaded? Or did you do anything else? Since it's now two years after you came up with this solution, have you found any better way of doing it?

Comment: @AndrewBate I've amended my description (which was wrong) and the code, though am unable to test it right now so let me know if you do, please. As you mention, I wrote this a long time ago for a specific use case, and haven't reattempted to the same goal since then so have no better alternative to suggest. I don't even know for sure the non-static initializer is necessary, I would have thought you could  simply call `loadClass` inside the constructor... but then again, I hopefully settled on this approach with good reason :)